# Android: How to get online or offline user status in quickblox?

Tags: java, android, chat, quickblox

I am not able to get user offline and online status in quickblox. In simple chat demo of quickblox. I am using [This](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat) demo for chatting. But that in i can't get user online offline status. and I have already search and refer many links but not get success. Thanks Advance.

Reffed links:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android
https://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/35/0/how-to-find-out-whether-quickblox-user-is-online
https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API

Comment: What code have those "many links" shown that you've tried?

Comment: sir check updated question. and code i haven't for that

Comment: What about this one? http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Online.5COffline_status

Comment: @cricket_007 that in when i am login that time can get status but when my app is in background nothing done that time i can't manage this.

Comment: @Ravi Vaghela Did you got any solution . If yes pls share it here.

Comment: @ADM no. Not got any solution for that

Comment: I have read the Docs, there is a Presence model and turns out it only work in case of Group chat . So What about Private Chat? Ok thx anyway.

Comment: There is Presence model and for private chat
https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Contact_list

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will help you.

```
Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Presence presence;

for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

    System.out.println(entry.getUser());
    System.out.println(presence.getType().name());
    System.out.println(presence.getStatus());
}
```